# How to use xmlportletfactory in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to render custom asset in asset publisher in `liferay dxp`. I am suggested to use `xmlportletfactory`. Can anyone explain me how to use it?

Comment: You can check their wiki: http://www.xmlportletfactory.org/wiki but I'm not sure they work with Liferay DXP yet.

Answer (score 0):

From [xmlportletfactory.org](http://xmlportletfactory.org):

> No more problems with versions. You make one XML file, generate
>   portlet in all 6.0.x, 6.1.x and 6.2.x versions of Liferay.

Your option, if you want to use it, is to generate the code for Liferay 6.2 and then port it to DXP. Not sure if this is a good approach if you use xmlportletfactory for learning about assets, but - with xmlportletfactory - it's the only one short of implementing it for Liferay 7 and DXP yourself or waiting for the upgrade to be done.